# Any way to auto add a quote mark around a character variable during implode for mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Here it is..

```
Foreach ($data as $x) {

$mydata =  implode( ", ", $x);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `wp_realty_listingsdb` (`listingsdb_id`, `user_id`, 
`class_id`, `MLS`, `DOM`, `Zip`, `Status`) VALUES($id, 1, 1, $mydata);";

echo "$sql<br>";

$id++;

}
```

Keep in mind this is a simplified example and there will be over 200 fields being imploded for insertion.. so there might be as many as 100+ character variables that will require tick encapsulation so if the implode won't do it then it could get complicated..

```
End result of echo the resultant sql..
Line 1:
INSERT INTO `wp_realty_listingsdb` (`listingsdb_id`, `user_id`,
`class_id`, `MLS`, `DOM`, `Zip`, `Status`) VALUES(2, 1, 1, 1475566, 626,
 89005, Sold);
Line 2:
INSERT INTO `wp_realty_listingsdb` (`listingsdb_id`, `user_id`, 
`class_id`, `MLS`, `DOM`, `Zip`, `Status`) VALUES(3, 1, 1, 1485995, 492, 
89005, 'Sold');
```

PROBLEM:  To use php insert the character variables require that it have a tick on each side of the variable like 'Sold' as you see in line 1 it will not put the tick on implode.. Line 2 is an example of where i manually added the tick.. and it works fine.. Is there anyway to have the implode add the ticks around any character variables... w/o extensive additional programming.

Comment: Isn't `$mydata =  "'" . implode( "', '", $x) . "'";` enough to do it?

Comment: Unless you are using the legacy mysql extension, deprecated several years ago and now gone from the language, you should really be using prepared statements. (BTW, do you really want a solution in the MySQL side?)

Comment: Thanks I will try that but won't that put a tick on each side of each variable.. as i only need the tick around the character varialbe.. since the number variables need to be kept as numbers and if i add ticks to all won't they all become character varialbes?

Comment: That's exactly the point: with prepared statements you don't need to worry about that, you just drop the appropriate placeholders (e.g. `?`).

Answer (score 0):

```
$xt = array_map(function($x){ return "'$x'";}, $x);
$mydata =  implode( ", ", $xt);
```

Apart from that the code is probably vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Here is the full implementation of what you said.. have i done anything wrong that you can see...

Comment: foreach ($listID as $x) {

      $xt = array_map(function($x) {  return "'$x'"}, $x);

      $mydata =  implode( ",", $xt);

      $sql = "INSERT INTO `wp_realty_listingsdb` (`listingsdb_id`, `user_id`, `class_id`, `MLS`, `DOM`, `Zip`, `Status`) VALUES($id, 1, 1, $mydata);";

      echo "$sql<br>";

      $id++;

Comment: When i tried the code above i got the following error..
[07-Jun-2017 22:16:44 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/sdfinecondos/public_html/phrets_bruce/bruce.php on line 17

Comment: Do you have the semicolon before the closing brace? I added it a few minutes later.